# Getting NoClassDefFoundError: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, mysql, exception, jdbc, noclassdeffounderror

I'm currently writing a jdbc client-server socket application in java. I've been having a bit of trouble initializing jdbc as i'm not using an ide, just a text editor and jdk. I have put my jdbc driver in my jdk and jre classpaths C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\jre\lib\ext and  \jre\lib\ext . I also renamed the jar to com.mysql.jdbc.driver , but I have still had no luck. Is this a problem with the driver not being found or is it something else?

Here is my error:

```
C:\Users\imallin\My Documents>java Provider
Waiting for connection
Connection received from 127.0.0.1
server>Hi welcome to the Cyfieithu Eadar-Theangachadh translation server, please
enter a command. Type cmd to see a list of commands
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at Provider.insertData(Provider.java:82)
    at Provider.run(Provider.java:40)
    at Provider.main(Provider.java:118)
```

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Provider{
ServerSocket providerSocket;
Socket connection = null;
ObjectOutputStream out;
ObjectInputStream in;
String message;
Connection con;
Provider(){}
void run()
{
        Console c = System.console();
    if (c == null) {
        System.err.println("No console.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    try{
        //1. creating a server socket
        providerSocket = new ServerSocket(2004, 10);
        //2. Wait for connection
        System.out.println("Waiting for connection");
        connection = providerSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("Connection received from " + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());
        //3. get Input and Output streams
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        out.flush();
        in = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
                        sendMessage("Hi welcome to the Cyfieithu Eadar-Theangachadh translation server, please enter a command. Type cmd to see a list of commands");
        //4. The two parts communicate via the input and output streams
        do{
            try{
                                    insertData();

            message = (String) in.readObject();
            System.out.println("client>" + message);
                                if (message.equals("register"))
                    sendMessage("first name?");
                    String firstName = (message);
                    sendMessage("first name = " + firstName);
                    insertData();
                                if (message.equals("listlanguages"))
                                sendMessage("English \n Thai \n Geordia \n Gaelic \n Welsh \n Gaelic \n Urdu \n Polish \n Punjabi \n Cantonese \n Mandarin");
                    if (message.equals("bye"))
                    sendMessage("bye");
                    }
            catch(ClassNotFoundException classnot){
                System.err.println("Data received in unknown format");
            }
            catch (Exception e){
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }while(!message.equals("bye"));
    }
    catch(IOException ioException){
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        //4: Closing connection
        try{
            in.close();
            out.close();
            providerSocket.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ioException){
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
    private void insertData()
{

    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");


        con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost/translator","root","");

String sql = "Insert INTO users (ID, firstName) VALUES ('123','123')";

        Statement statement = con.createStatement();

        statement.execute(sql);


    }
                    catch (Exception e){
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
    }


void sendMessage(String msg)
{
    try{
        out.writeObject(msg);
        out.flush();
        System.out.println("server>" + msg);
    }
    catch(IOException ioException){
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    Provider server = new Provider();
    while(true){
        server.run();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You haven't stated what error you're getting. That makes it pretty hard to give an answer...

Comment: Error: com.mysql.jdbc.driver
 That's all i'm getting from catching exception e

Comment: Please provide the error message and stacktrace.

Comment: I don't know how to get a more specific error, the error: com.mysql.jdbc.driver is all I am getting.

Comment: @user1080390: You get this short error message because of `System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());`. Replace that line with `e.printStackTrace()` - that should provide further details.

Comment: Just checking, are you sure the java executable you are using is the one located in "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\jre\bin" ?

Comment: I tried replacing it with e.printStackTrace() i'm now getting this error: Provider.java:97: 'void' type not allowed here System.err.println("Error: " + e.printStackTrace());

Comment: Why did you put the driver into the JDK/JRE extension folder? I'd say this needs to be an application dependency and thus be on the application's class path. Anyways, the naming should be independent and haveing a file name `com.mysql.jdbc.driver` for a jar looks like an error by itself already.

Comment: @user1080390 home said "replace the `System.err.println(...)` with `e.printStackTrace()` not only the  `e.getMessage()`.

Comment: I've edited my original post, it now contains the full error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like other answers have hinted already, the jdbc Jar is not on your classpath.

To fix this, you need to declare, when running your Java main file, that it should use that Jar, by doing:

```
java -cp "nameOfJar.jar" Provider
```

This is assuming that your jar is on the same dir as your Provider file, if not you should specify the path to it.

It's totally optional, but I like having a directory named "lib" where I put all the jars I need to run my project, then you can add to classpath by doing:

```
java -cp "./lib/*;." NameOfJavaClassWithMain
```

Ultimately, you might end up having several directories or jars that you need to add  to your classpath, you do this by using the `;` (`:` in linux) separator, like:

```
java -cp "./lib/*;./conf/configurationFile.properties;." NameOfJavaClassWithMain
```

If your .class is not on one of the Jars, you might have to add the local directory to your classpath:

```
java -cp "./lib/*;." NameOfJavaClassWithMain
```

If you have a package declaration on your class (you should), you need to reference the class by that fully classified name (package+ClassName), like so:

```
java -cp "./lib/*;." my.package.NameOfJavaClassWithMain
```

Comment: I ran "java -cp "postgresql-9.1-902.jdbc4.jar" Provider but I get a provider "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Provider.ClassNotFoundException

Comment: Can you update your question to have the command line you're calling now? And why do you have a postgres jar when you're instantiating a mysql Driver?

Comment: I'm going to go download the j connector from the mysql site. I may have the wrong jar.

Comment: I'm running java -cp "/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.20-bin" Provider - Still getting the same Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Provider Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Provider at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) at java.security.AccessController.doPriviledged(native method) etc...

Comment: Any ideas? I definitely have the right jar file, and the directory is correct

Comment: I don't see the .jar extension there... shouldn't it be something like: ava -cp "/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.20-bin.jar:." Provider

Comment: Yes, I have the following directory C:\Users\imallin\My Documents\provider in the provider folder I have my Provider.class file, and in my lib folder I have my jdbc jar file.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11024/discussion-between-user1080390-and-pcalcao)

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately your classpath for jdbc is not set.

This is what I do ( a bad practice )

extract your jar file. (say you are working in home directory ~, and the name of directory where jar file is extracted is odbc)
then set your classpath to

`export CLASSPATH=~/odbc:`

( do not forget to add `:` after the path ;-) )

Oh could not realize that you are working on windows machine.
Then
set environment variable ( create if does not exists ) CLASSPATH to `c:\odbcdir`

or other-way is to use `java -cp pathToJAR.jar Main`.

Comment: That's a little bit vague, how would I go about setting it?

Comment: I ran "java -cp "postgresql-9.1-902.jdbc4.jar" Provider but I get a provider "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Provider.ClassNotFoundException

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL Driver jar is not on the classpath. You need to fix this, by using the `-cp` argument to`java`.